# Playing audio using a jquery function

Tags: jquery, html, audio, embed

I am trying to play sound in background of my webpage

HTML:-

```
<audio id="bgm">
</audio>
```

JQUERY:-

```
function playSound(){
    var snd=document.getElementById('bgm');

    snd.src='mkbackground.mp3';
    snd.load();
    snd.play();
}
```

I am calling the function inside

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
playSound();
});
```

But it isn't working

Please help

Comment: The embed element does not have methods like `load`/`play` those are associated with `video`/`audio` elements

Comment: `var snd=$('#bgm').prop("src");` or `var snd=$('#bgm').attr("src");`
i'm not sure, but try one of these..

Comment: @ArunPJohny i have edited the question. It doesnt work for audio tags too.

Comment: @ManjunathHegde i tried that too but it isn't working

Comment: any error in the console

Comment: @ArunPJohny no there are no errors

Comment: @ArunPJohny and i am using an up-to-date version of Chrome if that is of any help